# Datetime Regular Expression Doesn't Work

Tags: regex, date, time, escaping, expression

I am having a hard time reading in string that has date and time in the format:

```
YYYYMMDDHHmmSS.FFFF[+|-]ZZzz
```

- `YYYY` is year,
- `MM` is month (starting at 01 to 12),
- `DD` is day (01-31),
- `HH` is hour (00-23),
- `mm` is minute (00-59),
- `SS` is second (00-59),
- `FFFF` is the fraction of the second (0000-9999),
- `ZZzz` is "difference in hours (ZZ – values from +14 to –12) and
  minutes (zz – values 00 to 59) from the Coordinated Universal Time
  (UTC)."

This is the standard for transferring date time information in HL7, but don't worry about that. The problem I am having is the system handling the regular expression I have written for this standard refuses to let me add the dot following the second field. It also will not allow for the plus or minus prior to the ZZ field.

Here is the regular expression I have written:

```
/^(1|2)\\d{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|(1|2)[0-9]|3(0|1))((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]\\.\\d{4}((\\+|\\-)0[0-9]|\\-1[0-2]|\\+1[0-4])[0-5][0-9]$/
```

Its for Limesurvey, for its validation field for a given question. If you don't know what that is, just know that its regular expressions use Perl conventions.

Note that if I remove the \., or the \+ \-, it works just fine (with the exception the regex is no longer enforcing the standard). I've also tried not escaping the backslash, but that doesn't do anything either.

If anyone could point to why this isn't working, I would appreciate it. Note that if anything looks odd or redundant in the regex, that's most likely from me logically breaking it into the various fields for easier readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I barely changed your regular expression up until the +14 through -12 part. I'm not quite You can see it working here: http://www.regex101.com/r/jF1bA9

**Final Regular Expression:**

```
^(1|2)[0-9]{3}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])((0[1-9])|((1|2)[0-9])|3(0|1))((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.[0-9]{4}(\+0[0-9]|\+1[0-4]|-0[0-9]|-1[0-2])[0-5][0-9]$
```

**Regular Expression explained:**

Start of the line:
`^`                               // start of line

Year:

`(1|2)[0-9]{3}`

Month:

`(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`

Day:

`((0[1-9])|((1|2)[0-9])|3(0|1))`

Hour:

`((0|1)[0-9]|2[0-3])`

Minutes:

`([0-5][0-9])`

Seconds:

`([0-5][0-9])`

Period:

`\.`

Fraction of the second:

`[0-9]{4}`

***Matches +14 through -12*** (What you probably need to change)

`(\+0[0-9]|\+1[0-4]|-0[0-9]|-1[0-2])`

> Matches:
>   +14 +13 +12 +11 +10 +09 +08 +07 +06 +05 +04 +03 +02 +01 +00 -00 -01 -02 -03 -04 -05 -06 -07 -08 -09 -10 -11 -12

00 - 59:

`[0-5][0-9]`

End of Line:

`$`

---

You may need to change it to work with your specific language (I saw you had double backslashes in some areas like `\\d`)